# How to generate migration by ormconfig.ts and .env?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, environment-variables, typeorm

Before adding `namingStrategy` I was able to use `.env`, which is

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=postgres
TYPEORM_HOST=localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME=someusername
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=somepassword
TYPEORM_DATABASE=somedb
TYPEORM_TEST_DATABASE=sometestdb
TYPEORM_TEST_DATABASE_PASSWORD=sometestdbpassword
TYPEORM_PORT=5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN=false
TYPEORM_DROP_SCHEMA=false
TYPEORM_LOGGING=true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES=src/entity/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS=src/migration/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS=src/subscriber/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR=src/entity
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR=src/migration
TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS_DIR=src/subscriber
```

And with typeorm command which generate migrations to **migration** folder:

```
ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n Init
```

So, now I need to add **namingStrategy with CustomNamingStrategy class**. But unfortunately [here](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-environment-variables) no any namingStrategy variable, so I have to create `ormconfig.ts`:

```
module.exports = {
  type: process.env.TYPEORM_CONNECTION,
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING,
  entities: [process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES],
  migrations: [process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS],
  subscribers: [process.env.TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR,
    migrationsDir: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR,
    subscribersDir: process.env.TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS_DIR,
  },
  namingStrategy: new CustomNamingStrategy()
};
```

And I used this command and this is not working:

```
ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./ormconfig.ts migration:generate -n Init
```

**How can I generate migration to migration folder with .env and ormconfig.ts configurations?**